# How to tell VSCode that python packages are in fact installed?

Tags: python, docker, pygame

I am building a Python application with the Pygame library and I am using Docker to containerize it.

Here is the `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM python

WORKDIR /app

COPY requirements.txt .

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

COPY . .

CMD ["python", "main.py"]
```

Here is `requirements.txt`:

```
autopep8==1.6.0
pygame==2.1.0
```

Here is the `docker-compose.yaml` file:

```yaml
version: "3.8"
services:
  app:
    build: ./
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
```

Here is `main.py`:

```py
import pygame

print("hello there")
```

This is what happens when I run `docker-compose up`:

```
Attaching to connect-four_app_1
app_1  | pygame 2.1.0 (SDL 2.0.16, Python 3.10.1)
app_1  | Hello from the pygame community. https://www.pygame.org/contribute.html
app_1  | hello there
connect-four_app_1 exited with code 0
```

As you can see, the application is working perfectly fine. The only problem is that in my `main.py` file, VSCode isn't able to find `pygame`, i.e. it thinks it isn't installed, and therefore I don't get any autocompletion for the library. How do I tell VSCode that `pygame` is in fact installed, but only in the container?

Thanks a bunch.

Comment: You cannot install it into VSCode ? VSCode cannot find dependecy because is not install in local.

Comment: So is there no solution?

Comment: The question is like can you read a book without opening it, yes it's probably on x-ray or I don't know, but the easiest way is still to open it ;)

Answer (score 1):

I have never worked with Docker so I do not know if this will help you. But my experience working with virtualenvs is that you should tell VS Code what Python interpreter you want it to use to run your code. Depending on where you have installed the packages, maybe you are using an interpreter that cannot reach the packages you have installed (maybe you have this package using a different Python installation, on a different directory).

Just to rule out that this is not the problem, try pressing F1 and then typing/selecting "Python: Select interpreter" on VS Code. And then you can go through all Python versions installed in your PC to see which one recognizes the packages you want. Hope this help you a bit.

Comment: Docker stores the dependencies along with the code of an application in an image, so VSCode would have no way on knowing that the dependencies are in fact, installed.